# How to invoke kubectl from Python subprocess.run in Windows with KUBECONFIG passed in via env argument

Tags: python, subprocess, kubectl

I'm getting the below error in Windows environment when invoking kubectl from Python subprocess.run with the KUBECONFIG variable being passed via the env argument.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'kubectl get ns' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I'm running the below code. It works just fine from a Linux terminal but not from Windows. I'm thinking if it is because of how the OS paths are written in Windows but I'm unable to get it working in Windows. The error that I get is also pasted below. Can somebody help please?

```
import subprocess
env_var = {'KUBECONFIG': '/home/myhome/.kube/config'} #For Linux
env_var = {'KUBECONFIG': 'C:\\Users\\myhome\\.kube\\config'} #For Windows
output = subprocess.run('kubectl get ns', shell=True, check=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=env_var)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'kubectl get ns' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if I append the additional environment variable(s) (ie: KUBECONFIG) to the existing ones. The issue was that without certain environment variables set the hostname in the KUBECONFIG file wasn't getting resolved.